# How to return object using list c#

Tags: c#, list, object, parameters, return

I have class Item.cs and I want return all items from my base with `List<Item>` ,....

so here is my code from WebService1.asmx

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Item> GetMyItems()
{
    List<Item> listOfItems= new List<Item>();
    Item add = new Item();

    using (var db = new Baza()) // into in my database (this works fine)
    {  
        var lookUp = from a in db.listOfItems
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = a.ID,
                         Name = a.name,
                         Year= a.year,
                         Price= a.price
                     };

        foreach (var item in lookUp)
        {
            if (item.Name == "Usb")
            {
                add.name = item.Name;
                add.year = item.Year;
                add.price = item.Price;
                listOfItems.Add(add);
            }
        }
        return listOfItems;
    }
}
```

and I want now use this object in another .cs file. On example "Program.cs"

So in program.cs I call method "GetMyItems":

```
List<Item> myItems = myService.GetMyItems();
```

I had include my own library for my class "Item.cs"

And on the end I get error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'myItems.ServiceReference1.Item[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<myLibrary.Item>'
```

My purpose is that I can in Program.cs use every property(in my case: name, year, price) for "listView"

For all the answers in advance thanks.

Comment: No. I use my own library with this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the method through the service it will automatically cast `List<Item>` to the basic data type `Item[]`.

To work around this I see two options:

1. Use the var keyword, and continue using the data type `Item[]`.

   ```
   var myItems = myService.GetMyItems();
   ```
2. Cast it back to `IEnumerable<Item>`:

   ```
   var myItems = myService.GetMyItems().ToList();
   ```

Comment: what about call function in program.cs?

Comment: Ok the problem, I think, is that when you call the method as a Service the List<Item> is converted to the basic type Item[]. I will change my example to make it simpler.